# highlight particular dates of all months using full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar to highlight dates from 10 to 15 of all months of current

year. but its not working. Please help. its showing blank page.

```
var myEvents = [];
var date = new Date();
var y = date.getFullYear();
var length=12;

for (var month = 1; month < length; month++){

    var startdate  = y+'-'+month+'-10';
    var enddate    = y+'-'+month+'-15';
    myEvents.push({

        title : 'event',
        start : startdate,
            end   : enddate,
        allDay : true

    });

}

$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', myEvents );
alert(myEvents);
```

Comment: any error from browser console?

Comment: no, not giving any error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your month should be two digits. Please add the below code.

```
var month = (month <= 9) ? '0' + month : month;
```

Comment: Thanks Venkat. Its showing calendar. But not highlighting particular dates of every month

Comment: thanks Venkat. I have done it. but can we give background colors to these cells. as I am using below code     title: 'event',
            start: startdate,
   backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
   end: enddate,   
            allDay: true   but its not working.